# Getting sequence of bytes (u8) from a char

Tags: rust

I need to examine the bytes that make up a character. I know it is possible to do so by going from a `char` to a `String` to a `&[u8]` like so:

```
let multi_byte_char = 'á';
let little_string = multi_byte_char.to_string();
let byte_slice = little_string.as_bytes();

for byte in byte_slice {
    println!("{}", byte); // Prints "195, 161"
}
```

Is there a way to go straight from a `char` to a `&[u8]`? I can't find anything in [the char documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html). Another option is to `mem::transmute` from a `char` to a `[u8; 4]`, but using unsafe code here seems silly.

EDIT: There is [an unstable `encode_utf8` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.encode_utf8) on `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me like what you want is [`encode_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.encode_utf8), but that is also unstable. You can see its implementation [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9cc0b2247509d61d6a246a5c5ad67f84b9a2d8b6/src/libcore/char.rs#L220).

Comment: Yes! That was what I was looking for. (I saw your answer just after I added my edit. Sorry for the strangeness there.)